# Why is the object destructor paradigm in garbage collected languages pervasively absent?

Tags: programming-languages, memory-management, garbage-collection, language-design

Looking for insight into decisions around garbage collected language design. Perhaps a language expert could enlighten me? I come from a C++ background, so this area is baffling to me.

It seems nearly all modern garbage collected languages with OOPy object support like Ruby, Javascript/ES6/ES7, Actionscript, Lua, etc. completely omit the destructor/finalize paradigm. Python seems to be the only one with its `class __del__()` method. Why is this? Are there functional/theoretical limitations within languages with automatic garbage collection which prevent effective implementations of a destructor/finalize method on objects?

I find it extremely lacking that these languages consider memory as the ***only*** resource worth managing. What about sockets, file handles, application states? Without the ability to implement custom logic to clean up non-memory resources and states on object finalization, I'm required to litter my application with custom `myObject.destroy()` style calls, placing the cleanup logic outside my "class", breaking attempted encapsulation, and relegating my application to resource leaks due to human error rather than automatically being handled by the gc.

What are the language design decisions which lead to these languages not having any way to execute custom logic on object disposal? I have to imagine there is a good reason. I'd like to better understand the technical and theoretical decisions that resulted in these languages not having support for object destruction/finalization.

**Update:**

Perhaps a better way to phrase my question:

Why would a language have the built-in concept of object instances with class or class-like structures along with custom instantiation (constructors), yet completely omit the destruction/finalize functionality? Languages which offer automatic garbage collection seem to be prime candidates to support object destruction/finalization as they know with 100% certainty when an object is no longer in use. Yet most of those languages do not support it.

I don't think it's a case where the destructor may never get called, as that would be a core memory leak, which gcs are designed to avoid. I could see a possible argument being that the destructor/finalizer may not get called until some indeterminate time in the future, but that didn't stop Java or Python from supporting the functionality.

What are the core language design reasons to not support any form of object finalization?

Comment: Maybe because `finalize`/`destroy` is a lie? There's no guarantee it'll ever be executed. And, even if, you don't know when (given automatic garbage collection), and if necessary context is still there (it may already have been collected). So it's safer to ensure consistent state in other ways, and one might want to force the programmer to do so.

Comment: I think this question is borderline offtopic. Is it a programming language design question of the kind we want to entertain, or is it a question for a site more oriented towards programming? Community votes, please.

Comment: It's a fine question in PL design, let's have it.

Comment: This isn't really a static/dynamic distinction. Many static languages do not have finalizers. In fact, aren't languages with finalizers in the minority?

Comment: think there is some question here... it would be better if you defined terms a bit more. java has a finally block that is not tied with object destruction but method exit. there are also other ways to deal with resources. eg in java, a connection pool can deal with connections that go unused [x] amt of time & reclaim them. not elegant but it works. part of the answer to your question is that garbage collection is roughly a nondeterministic, not instantaneous process and is not driven by objects not being used any more but by memory constraints/ ceilings being triggered.

Comment: Thanks for the insights everyone. I've updated the question at the bottom to hopefully make it more clear as to what I'm looking to learn and understand.

Comment: @AndrejBauer The question is fine though the statement about the 100% certainty
on what objects are reclaimed is technically incorrect without
adding further structure and processing to a basic garbage collector
(except for ref counting GC). The accepted answer is essentially
misleading as to what the real issues are, regarding the role of
garbage collection, how to properly communicate from application with
the GC, and what finalization is supposed to be used for. Actually Ref
Count is the one technique that most easily treats on equal footing
memory and other resources. (see my answer)

Comment: @babou: Sure, and if there's something false claimed in the question, that's another reason for a good answer. The best questions are often quite confused.

Comment: Let's get it right. I'm happy to change the accepted answer if there is a better one. I accepted the current answer because it was the best at the time and it appeared there wasn't much activity/interest from the community. Now that things are picking up around this, we can hone in on what the right answer is. Certainly appreciate the desire to provide a correct and thorough answer.

Comment: Your view of it is perfectly respectable. The main problem is that you
do not react at all to new answers. So it is hard to know whether we
misunderstand your concern, or whether the answer is too obscure or
complex, and where. Accepting the answer is one thing, but you can
also vote, **and you can make comments**, asking for details or
justifications. I understand that you would want garbage collectors to
do the work, which I think is the right attitude, but garbage
collection technology is varied and sometimes subtle, and may be
sensitive to language design, which opens too many doors.

Comment: @babou: Two new answers were posted in the past 24hrs. Getting upset with me because I don't comment on them in some preconceived timeframe isn't productive. I'm quite busy this week. I will get around to it. Yes, it would be great if languages offered destructor-like functionality, but I know it's unlikely to happen. I'm looking to better understand the nuances of why some languages chose to not implement that functionality while languages like Python and Java did. This is an intellectual curiosity and not a need from a production level problem, which is why I posted the question in CS.

Comment: Sorry. I did not mean to sound upset. I was only suggesting that
minimal feedback, including `very busy, give me a week` gives the
feeling someone is still on the other end. These answers can be
significant work, and your question is not a simple one. You would not
believe the number of time hard work technical answers are being
ignored by the poster of the question. Your question is a good one. I
think the main point is that the best GC identify unused memory, not
unused objects as you believed (unlike the reference count GC), and
getting to objects requires further implementation complexity.

Comment: OP @dbcb, Java supports destructors. **So you don't consider Java a modern language?**

Comment: @Raphael,  Re "*And, even if, you don't know **when** (given automatic garbage collection)*", you sure **do know when**. Automatic garbage collection is guaranteed to run **when** you run out of memory.

Comment: @AndrejBauer, It's not a  static/dynamic distinction at all. The "static way" hooks a function into the GC, whereas the "dynamic way" is completely different and offers no way to hook into the GC.

Comment: @vzn, Java has finalizers too..

Comment: @Pacerier That's a trivial and rather useless upper bound. What about all the programs that never run out of memory? Remember that, in the conceptual world, we have infinite memory; otherwise the halting problem is trivially computable and we can't learn anything.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The pattern you're talking about, where objects know how to clean their resources up, falls into three relevant categories.  Let's not conflate *destructors* with *finalizers* - only one is related to garbage collection:

- The [finalizer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finalizer): cleanup method declared automatically, defined by programmer, called automatically.

  Finalizers are called automatically before deallocation by a garbage collector.  The term applies if the garbage collection algorithm employed can determine object life cycles.
- The [destructor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Destructor_(computer_programming)): cleanup method declared automatically, defined by programmer, called automatically only sometimes.

  Destructors can be called automatically for stack-allocated objects (because object lifetime is deterministic), but must be explicitly called on all possible execution paths for heap-allocated objects (because object lifetime is nondeterministic).
- The [disposer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispose_pattern): cleanup method declared, defined, and called by programmer.

  Programmers make a disposal method and call it themselves - this is where your custom `myObject.destroy()` method falls.  If disposal is absolutely required, then disposers must be called on all possible execution paths.

**Finalizers are the droids you're looking for.**

The finalizer pattern (the pattern your question is asking about) is the mechanism for associating objects with system resources (sockets, file descriptors, etc.) for mutual reclamation by a garbage collector. But, finalizers are fundamentally at the mercy of the garbage collection algorithm in use.

Consider this assumption of yours:

> Languages which offer automatic garbage collection ... know with 100% certainty when an object is no longer in use.

Technically false (thank you, @babou).  Garbage collection is fundamentally about memory, not objects.  If or when a collection algorithm realizes an object's memory is no longer in use depends on the algorithm and (possibly) how your objects refer to each other.  Let's talk about two types of runtime garbage collectors.  There are lots of ways to alter and augment these to basic techniques:

1. *Tracing GC.*  These trace memory, not objects.  Unless augmented to do so, they don't maintain back references to objects from memory.  Unless augmented, these GCs won't know when an object can be finalized, even if they know when its memory is unreachable.  Hence, finalizer calls aren't guaranteed.
2. *Reference Counting GC*. These use objects to track memory.  They model object reachability with a directed graph of references.  If there is a cycle in your object reference graph, then all objects in the cycle will never have their finalizer called (until program termination, obviously).  Again, finalizer calls are not guaranteed.

## TLDR

Garbage collection is difficult and diverse.  A finalizer call cannot be guaranteed before program termination.

Comment: You are correct that this isn't static v. dynamic. It's an issue with garbage collected languages. Garbage collection is a complex problem and is probably the primary reason as there are many edge cases to consider (e.g. what happens if logic in `finalize()` causes the object being cleaned up to be referenced again?). However, being unable to guarantee the finalizer being called before program termination didn't stop Java from supporting it. Not saying your answer is incorrect, just perhaps incomplete. Still a very good post. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Here's an attempt at completing my answer:  By explicitly omitting finalizers, a language forces its users to manage their own resources.  For many types of problems, that's probably a disadvantage.  Personally, I prefer Java's choice, because I have the power of finalizers *and* there's nothing stopping me from writing and using my own disposer.  Java's saying, "Hey, programmer.  You're not an idiot, so here's a finalizer.  Just be careful."

Comment: Updated my original question to reflect that this deals with garbage collected languages. Accepting your answer. Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Comment: Happy to help.  Did my comment clarification make my answer clearer?

Comment: It's good. To me, the real answer here is that languages choose not to implement it because the perceived value does not outweigh the problems of implementing the functionality. It's not impossible (as Java and Python demonstrate), but there is a trade off that many languages choose not to make.

Comment: Sounds good to me.  That's a lot more concise than I managed to be.

Comment: Garbage collection is a requirement for type safety.  Without garbage collection, you would need some other compiler certification of correct pointer usage.  

If you define an object (which is generally stateful), there needs to be a well defined protocol (a well defined grammar for method invoke patterns) for using it correctly.

Comment: @Rob, that's actually a [point of contention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3AType_safety#Garbage_Collection_Confusion).  Can you cite a source?

Comment: Ok, weaken "type safety" to "referential integrity" of an object graph.  If you have an int* that points to neither NULL or an int, then you do not have type safety.  I don't think it's contentious at all if you weaken it to "referential integrity".  But the point being made is that garbage collection is not really about cleaning up resources beyond the fact that if you can't prove that memory is properly handled then the graph of references lacks integrity.

Comment: And I did note "some other compiler certification", specifically for cases like Rust.  If the compiler can prove that memory is handled correctly then garbage collection is not needed.  But take a look at what must be done to make that work.  The type system must be rich enough to encode necessary pointer constraints.

Comment: @Rob, your statement, "garbage collection is not really about cleaning up resources," disagrees with my research.  Type safety and referential integrity are definitely related to garbage collection, but I don't think they're the core of the problem.

Comment: Lazy garbage collection only makes it safe to continually allocate memory with a bounded working set size; and it's never guaranteed to run - so it can't safely tie up resources.  So that's what I mean.

On the other hand, if you really do want to tie memory references to resource allocations, you really need reference counting or explicit lifetimes through object protocols (construct -> [read|write]* -> dispose).  You need objects with a Dispose method that gets called in a timely fashion (ie: object protocol handling resources).

Comment: Since you suggested I comment, I think that the issue of generational
collectors is irrelevant here. They are essentially tracing
collectors. The heuristic part has no effect on whether proper
collection will take place, but only when there will be a full cycle
reclaiming everything unreachable. Full cycle can be triggered any
time if need be, so that this is not an issue. So this has no serious
impact on finalizers. Also your last sentence is disputable. It is
actually easy to finalize everything that has not been yet just before
terminating execution. My comment to @dbcb is no critic to you.

Comment: To be fully accurate, actually, generational GC may raise new problems
because the organization of memory it requires (generation entry
points) could make it harder to identify object types when memory is
reclaimed. This would really require a more detailed analysis as it
depends on the specific of the organization of generation and their
entry points, as well as on the specific strutures used to identify
dying objects. It makes implementation harder, but I am sure it can be
dealt with. But these remarks apply in a general way to all variations
of tracing collectors (distributed for example).

Comment: @babou, Interesting.. Generational GC (Java's, at least) *does* maintain references to objects for finalizer calls. I thought Tracing GC strictly didn't do that?

Comment: There are various ways this can be done (no idea how Java actually
does it). One simple way is to maintain a table of objects, pointing
to all objects, but ignored by the GC so that objects can die (weak
pointers). After a GC cycle, the table can be used to identify and
finalize dying objects. In a copy collection, table pointers are
updated to new address of objects moved to newspace. Whatever pointer
is left pointing to oldspace points to a dying object that can be
finalized. This can work for generational GC. But there may be more
subtle techniques that raise problems. Is it what you meant?

Comment: @babou Ok, neat.  Do you know of any Tracing GC which can't use that technique? Or can any Tracing GC be instrumented with a weak reference table?

Comment: This may not always be the best technique (in time or space) and devil
is in the details, as always. But my guess (only a hunch) is that it
should work for all tracing GC. In the case of mark-and-sweep, you
have to be careful not to destroy too early the data for the dying
objects. Some algorithms sweep with compaction, or put links to chain
free chunks of memory, and may thus overwrite data needed for
finalization. So you probably want to finalize after marking, but
before sweeping. But you need the table only for objects to be
finalized, I think. What is your research about?

Comment: @kdbanman, There's an important detail you left out. While it's true that a finalizer call is not guaranteed before program termination, (in fact a "program" is never guaranteed to terminate anyway), it's also true that  **the call is guaranteed** before  the program ran out of memory. This is an important distinction and **the fundamental use case for finalizers**, that of affording memory, not provision of resource ids. If the GC does not call finalizer before the program halts or crash due to OOM, then it's a bug with the GC which needs to be fixed.

Comment: @Pacerier "_ it's also true that the call is guaranteed before the program ran out of memory._"   That is only true if the object actually gets flagged for collection.  That is the responsibility of the GC and the programmer.  If the programmer does their job correctly, then you're right.  The finalizer will absolutely get called before the program encounters OOM errors, provided the GC is implemented correctly.  However, if the programmer has not their job correctly, then no such guarantee can be made.

Answer (score 5):

### In a nutshell

Finalization is not a simple matter to be handled by garbage
collectors.  It is easy to use with reference counting GC, but this
family of GC is often incomplete, requiring memory leaks to be
compensated for by explicit triggering of destruction and
finalization of some objects and structures. Tracing garbage collectors are much more effective, but
they make it much harder to identify object to be finalized and
destroyed, as opposed to just identifying the unused memory, thus requiring
more complex management, with a cost in time and space, and in complexity
of the implementation.

### Introduction

I assume that what you are asking is why garbage collected languages
do not automatically handle destruction/finalization within the
garbage collection process, as indicated by the remark:

> I find it extremely lacking that these languages consider memory as the only resource worth managing. What about sockets, file handles, application states?

I disagree with the accepted [answer given by kdbanman](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/37462/why-is-the-object-destructor-paradigm-in-garbage-collected-languages-pervasively/37568#37568). While the facts stated there are
mostly correct, though strongly biased towards reference
counting, I do not believe they properly explain the situation
complained about in the question.

I do not believe that the terminology developed in that answer is much
of an issue, and it is more likely to confuse things. Indeed, as presented, the
terminology is mostly determined by the way the procedures are
activated rather than by what they do. The point is that in all cases,
there is the need to finalize an object no longer needed with some
cleanup process and to free whatever resources it has been using,
memory being just one of them. Ideally, all of it should be done
automatically when the object is no longer to be used, by means of a
garbage collector. In practice, GC may be missing or have
deficiencies, and this is compensated for by explicit triggering by
the program of finalization and reclamation.

Explicit trigerring by the program is a problem since it can allow for
hard to analyze programming errors, when an object still in use is
being explicitly terminated.

Hence it is much better to rely on automatic garbage collection to
reclaim resources. But there are two issues:

- some garbage collection technique will allow memory leaks that
  prevent full reclamation of resources. This is well known for
  reference counting GC, but may appear for other GC techniques when
  using some data organizations without care (point not discussed
  here).
- while GC technique may be good at identifying memory resources no
  longer used, finalizing objects contained therein may not be simple, and
  that complicates the problem of reclaiming other resources used by
  these objects, which is often the purpose of finalization.

Finally, an important point often forgotten is that GC cycles can be
triggered by anything, not just memory shortage, if the proper hooks
are provided and if the cost of a GC cycle is considered worth
it. Hence it is perfectly OK to initiate a GC when any kind of
resource is missing, in the hope of freeing some.

### Reference counting garbage collectors

**Reference counting is a weak garbage collecting
technique**, that will not handle cycles properly. It would indeed be
weak on destructing obsolete structures, and reclaiming other resources
simply because it is weak on reclaiming memory. But finalizers can be
used most easily with a reference counting garbage collector (GC),
since a ref-count GC does reclaims a structure when its ref count goes
down to 0, at which time its address is know together with its type,
either statically or dynamically. Hence it is possible to reclaim the
memory precisely after applying the proper finalizer, and calling
recursively the process on all pointed objects (possibly via the finalizing
procedure).

In a nutshell, finalization is easy to implement with Ref Counting GC,
but suffers from the "incompleteness" of that GC, indeed due to
circular structures, to precisely the same extent that memory
reclamation suffers. In other word, **with reference count, memory is
precisely as poorly managed as other resources** such as sockets, file
handles, etc.

Indeed, **Ref Count GC inability to reclaim looping structures (in
general) may be seen as memory leak**. You cannot expect all GC to avoid
memory leaks. It depends on the GC algorithm, and on the type
structure information dynamically available (for example in
[conservative GC](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/conservative.html)).

### Tracing garbage collectors

**The more powerful family of GC, without such leaks, is the
tracing family** that explores the live parts of the memory, starting
from well identified root pointers. All parts of the memory that are
not visited in this tracing process (which can actually be decomposed
in various ways, but I have to simplify) are unused parts of the
memory that can be thus reclaimed<sup>1</sup>. These collectors will reclaim all
memory parts that can no longer be accessed by the program, no matter
what it does. It does reclaim circular structures, and the more
advanced GC are based on some variation of this paradigm, sometimes
highly sophisticated. It can be combined with reference counting in
some cases, and compensate for its weaknesses.

A problem is that **your statement** (at the end of the question):

> Languages which offer automatic garbage collection seem to be prime candidates to support object destruction/finalization as they know with 100% certainty when an object is no longer in use.

**is technically incorrect** for tracing collectors.

What is known with 100% certainty is what parts of memory are *no
longer in use*. (More precisely, it should be said that they are *no longer accessible*, because some parts,
that can no longer be used according to the logic of the program, are
still considered in use if there is still a useless pointer to them in the program data.) But further processing and appropriate structures are needed to know
what *unused objects* may have been stored in these now *unused parts of
the memory*. This cannot be determined from what is known of the program, since the
program is no longer connected to these parts of the memory.

Thus after a pass of garbage collection, you are left with fragments
of memory that contain objects which are no longer in use, but there
is a priori no way to know what these objects are so as to apply the correct
finalization. Furthermore, if the tracing collector is the
mark-and-sweep type, it may be that some of the fragments may contain
objects that have already been finalized in a previous GC pass, but
were not used since for fragmentation reasons. However this can be
dealt with using extended explicit typing.

While a simple collector would just reclaim these fragments of memory,
without further ado, finalization require a specific pass to explore
that unused memory, identify the objects there contained, and apply
finalization procedures. But such an exploration requires
determination of the type of objects that were stored there, and type determination is also needed to apply the proper finalization, if any.

So that implies extra costs in GC time (the extra pass) and possibly
extra memory costs to make proper type information available during
that pass by diverse techniques. These costs may be significant as one
will often want to finalize only a few objects, while the time and space
overhead could concern all objects.

Another point is that the time and space overhead may concern program
code execution, and not just the GC execution.

I cannot give a more precise answer, pointing at specific issues,
because I do not know the specifics of many of the languages you
list. In the case of C, typing is a very difficult issue that lead to
the development of conservative collectors. My guess would be that
this affects also C++, but I am no expert on C++. This seems to be [confirmed by Hans Boehm](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/) who did much of the
research on conservative GC. Conservative GC cannot reclaim
systematically all unused memory precisely because it may lack precise
type information on data. For the same reason, it would not be able to
systematically apply finalizing procedures.

So, it is possible to do what you are asking, as you know from some
languages. But it does not come for free. Depending on the language and its implementation, it may entail a cost even when you do not use the feature.
Various techniques and trade-offs can be considered to address these issues, but that is beyond the scope of a reasonably sized answer.

<sub>1 - this is an abstract presentation of tracing collection (encompassing both copy and mark-and-sweep GC), things vary according to the type of tracing collector, and exploring the unused part of memory is different, depending on whether copy or mark and sweep is used.</sub>

Comment: You give a lot of great details on garbage collection.  However, your answer doesn't actually disagree with mine - your abstract and my TLDR are essentially saying the same thing.  And for what it's worth, my answer uses reference counting GC as an example, not a "strong bias".

Comment: After reading more thoroughly, I see the disagreement.  I'll edit accordingly.  Also, my terminology was to be unambiguous.  The question was conflating finalizers and destructors, and even mentioned disposers in the same breath.  Its worthwhile to spread the right words.

Comment: @kdbanman The difficulty was that I was addressing both of you, since
your answer was standing as reference. You cannot use ref count as a
paradigmatic example because it is a weak GC, seldom used in languages
(check the languages cited by the OP), for which adding finalizers
would actually be easy (but with limited use). Tracing collectors are
almost always used. But finalizers are hard to hook on them, because
dying objects are not known (contrary to the statement you consider
correct). Distinction between static and dynamic typing is irrelevant,
by dynamic typing of data store is essential.

Comment: @kdbanman Regarding terminology, it is useful in general, as it correspond to
different situations. But here it does not help, since the question is
about transfering finalization to the GC. The basic GC is supposed to
do the destruction only. What is needed is a terminology that
distinguish `getting memory recycled`, which I call `reclamation`, and
doing some clean-up before that, such as reclaiming other resources or
updating some object tables, which I call `finalization`. These seemed
to me the relevant issues, but I may have missed a point in your
terminology, which was new to me.

Comment: I think I understand what you're getting at now.  My understanding of garbage collecters was much more incomplete than I thought.  Your answer and other reading has filled some gaps and I've updated my answer pretty comprehensively to match.  Thanks for the critique.  I love learning.  Let me know if you spot other inconsistencies.

Comment: Thanks @kdbanman, babou. Good discussion. I think both of your posts cover similar points. As both of you point out, the core issue appears to be the category of garbage collector employed in the language's runtime. I found [this article](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/09/03/visualizing-garbage-collection-algorithms/), which clears up some misconceptions for me. It seems the more robust gcs only handle low level raw memory, which renders higher level object types opaque to the gc. Without knowledge of the memory internals, the gc cannot destruct objects. Which seems to be your conclusion.

Comment: @dbcb Glad you are finding this exchange fruitful. However, I have a
small problem with your view of the rules of the game. I gave a very
complete answer, emphasizing the major issues of the problem. Then
kdbanman corrected his answer to take into account my contribution,
including my criticisms of his initial answer, very fairly attributing
it to me. No issue with that, though I would proceed
differently. Thus, we cover similar points. But who brought them? I
think the game we play on this site has rules. Are you following them?
Of course you are free to do as you will, but is it ethical?

Comment: @dbcb The paper you cite seems very basic and apparently does not
address your question here about finalization.

Answer (score 4):

The object destructor pattern is fundamental to error handling in systems programming, but has nothing to do with garbage collection.  Rather, it has to do with matching object lifetime to a scope, and can be implemented/used in any language that has first class functions.

Example (pseudocode).  Suppose you have a "raw file" type, like the Posix file descriptor type.  There are four fundamental operations, `open()`, `close()`, `read()`, `write()`.  You would like to implement a "safe" file type that always cleans up after itself.  (I.e., that has an automatic constructor and destructor.)

I'll assume our language has exception handling with `throw`, `try` and `finally` (in languages without exception handling you can set up a discipline where the user of your type returns a special value to indicate an error.)

You set up a function that accepts a function that does the work.  The worker function accepts one argument (a handle to the "safe" file).

```
with_file_opened_for_read (string:   filename,
                           function: worker_function(safe_file f)):
  raw_file rf = open(filename, O_RDONLY)
  if rf == error:
    throw File_Open_Error

  try:
    worker_function(rf)
  finally:
    close(rf)
```

You also provide implementations of `read()` and `write()` for `safe_file` (that just call the `raw_file` `read()` and `write()`).  Now the user uses the `safe_file` type like this:

```
...
with_file_opened_for_read ("myfile.txt",
                           anonymous_function(safe_file f):
                             mytext = read(f)
                             ... (including perhaps throwing an error)
                          )
```

A C++ destructor is really just syntactic sugar for a `try-finally` block.  Pretty much all I've done here is convert what a C++ `safe_file` class with a constructor and destructor would compile into.  Note that C++ doesn't have `finally` for its exceptions, *specifically* because Stroustrup felt that using an explicit destructor was better syntactically (and he introduced it into the language before the language had anonymous functions).

(This is a simplification of one of the ways that people have been doing error handling in Lisp-like languages for many years.  I think I first ran into it in the late 1980s or early 1990s, but I don't remember where.)

Comment: This describes the internals of the stack based destructor pattern in C++, but doesn't explain why a garbage collected language would not implement such functionality. You may be right that this has nothing to do with garbage collection, but it is related to general object destruction/finalization, which appears to be difficult or inefficient in garbage collected languages. So if the general destruction isn't supported, the stack based destruction seems to be omitted as well.

Comment: As I said at the beginning: any garbage collected language that has first class functions (or some approximation of first class functions) gives you the ability to provide "bullet proof" interfaces like `safe_file` and `with_file_opened_for_read` (an object that closes itself when it goes out of scope).  That's the important thing, that it doesn't have the same syntax as constructors is irrelevant.  Lisp, Scheme, Java, Scala, Go, Haskell, Rust, Javascript, Clojure all support sufficient first class functions, so they don't need destructors to provide the same useful feature.

Comment: I think I see what you're saying. Since languages provide the basic building blocks (try/catch/finally, first class functions, etc.) to manually implement destructor-like functionality, they don't need destructors? I could see some languages taking that route for reasons of simplicity. Although, it seems unlikely that's the primary reason for all the languages listed, but perhaps that's what it is. Maybe I'm just in the vast minority who love C++ destructors and nobody else really cares, which could very well be the reason why most languages don't implement destructors. They just don't care.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a full answer to the question, but I wanted to add a couple of observations that haven't been covered in the other answers or comments.

1. The question implicitly assumes that we're talking about a Simula-style object oriented language, which is itself limiting. In most languages, even those with objects, not everything is an object. The machinery to implement destructors would impose a cost which not every language implementor is willing to pay.
2. C++ has some implicit guarantees about destruction order. If you have a tree-like data structure, for example, the children will be destroyed before the parent. This is not the case in GC'd languages, so hierarchical resources may be released in an unpredictable order. For non-memory resources, this can matter.

Answer (score 2):

When the of two most popular GC frameworks (Java and .NET) were being designed, I think the authors expected that finalization would work well enough to avoid the need for other forms of resource management.  Many aspects of language and framework design can be greatly simplified if there's no need for all features necessary to accommodate 100% reliable and deterministic resource management.  In C++, it's necessary to distinguish between the concepts of:

1. Pointer/reference that identifies an object which is exclusively owned by the holder of the reference, and which is not identified by any pointers/references the owner doesn't know about.
2. Pointer/reference that identifies a sharable object which isn't exclusively owned by anyone.
3. Pointer/reference that identifies an object which is exclusively *owned* by the holder of the reference, but to which may be accessible through "views" the owner has no way of tracking.
4. Pointer/reference that identifies an object which is provides a view of an object which is owned by someone else.

If a GC language/framework don't have to worry about resource management, all of the above can be replaced by a single kind of reference.

I would find naïve the idea that finalization would eliminate the need for other forms of resource management, but whether or not such expectation was been reasonable at the time, history has since shown that there are many cases that require more precise resource management than finalization provides.  I happen to think that rewards of recognizing ownership at the language/framework level would be sufficient to justify the cost (the complexity has to exist somewhere, and moving it to the language/framework would simplify user code) but do recognize that there are significant design benefits to having a single "kind" of reference--something which only works if the language/framework are agnostic to issues of resource cleanup.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is the object destructor paradigm in garbage collected languages pervasively absent?
>
> I come from a C++ background, so this area is baffling to me.

The destructor in C++ actually does **two** **things** combined. It frees RAM and it frees resource ids.

Other languages [separate](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=separation+of+concerns) these concerns by having the GC be in charge of freeing RAM while another language feature take charge of freeing resource ids.

> I find it extremely lacking that these languages consider memory as the only resource worth managing.

That's what GCs are all about. They only dono **one thing** and it is to ensure that you don't run out of memory. If RAM is infinite, all GCs would be retired as there is no longer any real reason for them to exist.

> What about sockets, file handles, application states?

Languages can provide different ways of freeing resource ids by:

- manual [`.CloseOrDispose()`](http://archive.is/V79hO#selection-1145.19-1193.2) scattered across code
- manual `.CloseOrDispose()` scattered within manual "[`finally`](http://archive.is/V79hO#selection-1683.0-1685.1) block"
- manual "resource id blocks" (i.e. [`using`](http://archive.is/V79hO#selection-1807.0-1807.5), [`with`](http://archive.is/V79hO#selection-2019.0-2021.1), [`try`-with-resources](http://archive.is/V79hO#selection-2083.0-2115.2), etc) which automates `.CloseOrDispose()` after the block is *done*
- **guaranteed "resource id blocks" which automates `.CloseOrDispose()`** after the block is *done*

Many languages use manual (as opposed to guaranteed) mechanisms which creates an opportunity for resource mismanagement. Take this simple NodeJS code:

```
require('fs').openSync('file1.txt', 'w');
// forget to .closeSync the opened file
```

..where the programmer has forgotten to close the opened file.

For as long as the program keeps running, the opened file would be stuck in limbo. This is easy to verify by trying to open the file using HxD and verifying that it can't be done:

[image]

Freeing resource ids within C++ destructors is also non-guaranteed. You might think RAII operates like guaranteed "resource id blocks", yet unlike "resource id blocks", the C++ language does not stop the object providing the RAII block from being **leaked**, so the RAII block may never be *done*.

---

> It seems nearly all modern garbage collected languages with OOPy object support like Ruby, Javascript/ES6/ES7, Actionscript, Lua, etc. completely omit the destructor/finalize paradigm. Python seems to be the only one with its class `__del__()` method. Why is this?

Because they manage resource ids using other ways, as mentioned above.

> What are the language design decisions which lead to these languages not having any way to execute custom logic on object disposal?

Because they manage resource ids using other ways, as mentioned above.

> Why would a language have the built-in concept of object instances with class or class-like structures along with custom instantiation (constructors), yet completely omit the destruction/finalize functionality?

Because they manage resource ids using other ways, as mentioned above.

> I could see a possible argument being that the destructor/finalizer may not get called until some indeterminate time in the future, but that didn't stop Java or Python from supporting the functionality.

Java doesn't have destructors.

The [Java docs mention](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize--):

> the usual purpose of finalize, however, is to perform cleanup actions before the object is irrevocably discarded. For example, the finalize method for an object that represents an input/output connection might perform explicit I/O transactions to break the connection before the object is permanently discarded.

..but putting resource-id management code within `Object.finalizer` is largely regarded as an anti-pattern ([cf.](https://www.google.com/search?q=java%20%22finalize%22%20anti%20pattern)). Those code should instead be written at the call site.

For people who use the anti-pattern, their justification is that they **might have forgotten** to release the resource-ids at the call site. Thus, they do it *again* in the finalizer, just in case.

> What are the core language design reasons to not support any form of object finalization?

There are not many use cases for finalizers as they are for running a piece of code between the time when there are no longer any strong references to the object, and the time when it's memory is reclaimed by the GC.

A possible use case is when you'd like to keep a log of the time between the object is collected by the GC and the time when there are no longer any strong references to the object, as such:

```
finalize() {
    Log(TimeNow() + ". Obj " + toString() + " is going to be memory-collected soon!"); // "soon"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The RAII pattern in C++ is very powerful when you have deterministic object lifetime (stack objects go out of scope, heap objects are deleted), it is widely used to manage both memory and other resources (usually more precious, like file handles, sockets, locks, etc.).

However in GC languages where objects have indeterministic lifetime (GC only happens when there is a memory shortage, or not happen at all if program finishes quickly), it becomes necessary to treat memory management and more precious resource management separately. In these GC languages, these precious resources are usually managed through explicit method call (close(), unlock(), etc.), and sometimes with the help from other language constructs like "try...finally (Java)" or "with .... as ... (Python)".

Answer (score -1):

found a ref on this in Dr Dobbs wrt c++ that has more general ideas that argues destructors are problematic in a language where they are implemented. a rough idea here seems to be that a main purpose of destructors is to handle memory deallocation, and that is hard to accomplish correctly. memory is allocated piecewise but different objects get connected and then the deallocation responsibility/ boundaries are not so clear.

so the solution to this of a garbage collector evolved years ago, but garbage collection is not based on objects disappearing from scope at method exits (that is a conceptual idea that is hard to implement), but on a collector running periodically, somewhat nondeterministically, when the app experiences "memory pressure" (ie running out of memory).

in other words the mere human concept of an "newly unused object" is actually in some ways a misleading abstraction in the sense that no object can "instantaneously" become unused. unused objects can only be "discovered" by running a garbage collection algorithm that traverses the object reference graph and the best performing algorithms run intermittently.

it is possible a better garbage collection algorithm lies waiting to be discovered that can near-instantaneously identify unused objects, which could then lead to consistent destructor calling code, but one has not been found after many years of research in the area.

the solution to resource management areas such as files or connections seems to be to have object "managers" that attempt to handle their use.

- [Destructors considered harmful](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/destructors-considered-harmful/232300573) / Koenig, Dr Dobbs

Comment: Interesting find. Thanks. The author's argument is based on the destructor getting called at the wrong time due to passing class instances by value where the class doesn't have a proper copy constructor (which is a real problem). However, this scenario doesn't really exist in most (if not all) modern dynamic languages because everything is passed by reference which avoids the author's situation. Although this is an interesting perspective, I don't think it explains why most garbage collected languages have chosen to omit destructor/finalization functionality.

Comment: This answer misrepresents the Dr. Dobb's article: the article does not argue that destructors are problematic in general. The article actually argues this: *Memory management primitives are like goto statements, because they are both simple but too powerful. In the same way that goto statements are best encapsulated in "appropriately limited control structures" (See: Dijktsra), memory management primitives are best encapsulated in "appropriately limited data structures." Destructors are a step in this direction, but not far enough.*  Decide for yourself whether or not that's true.